# How To Fade In A Preloaded Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, preloader

My JavaScript FadeOut works fine but FadeIN does not work.

I have tried to FadeIn with different codes but the FadeIn effect does not work.

When my page is about to load, my Preloaded just appears like a still image but when the page is done loading, my Preloaded FadeOut smoothly.

I am trying to make my Preloaded FadeIn smoothly just as the FadeOut does.

Below is my JavaScript code.

```js
/* Preloader Javascript */

$(window)

.load(function(){$("#status")

.fadeOut("slow");$("#preloader")

.delay(1000)

.fadeOut(1000)
```

```css
/* Preloader CSS */
#preloader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 99999;
    height: 100%;
}
#status {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    margin: -32px 0 0 -32px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='preloader'><div id='status'><img alt='' src='https://www.blogger.com/img/gear.gif'/></div></div>
```

Comment: [.load(function)](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) has been deprecated for many years

Comment: @charlietfl so whats the solution?